# Can't change SSH_AUTH_SOCK with launchctl setenv

Tags: macos, ssh, shell, environment-variables, launchd

I want to set the value of `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` to a different location on an OSX El Capitan system. I attempted to do so by executing the following command:

```
$ launchctl setenv SSH_AUTH_SOCK ~/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh
```

However, `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` still holds the default value even after I restart the terminal:

```
$ echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.XXXXXXXXXX/Listeners
```

But interestingly, when I query the value of `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` using `launchctl`, I get the desired result:

```
$ launchctl getenv SSH_AUTH_SOCK
/Users/sora/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh
```

How can I correctly set the value of `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` system-wide?

EDIT: `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` was not set in any of the shell startup files (e.g. `~/.zshrc`, `/etc/zshrc`, `/etc/zprofile`)

Comment: Did you try to re-login or reboot?

Comment: @Jakuje Yes, but the problem persisted after reboot.

Comment: Run into absolutely same issue! I know it's 2 years old question, but did you manage to solve it? This still persists on High Sierra. So weird... Even Apples launchd doesn't work on their own OS as expected...

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a direct solution. However, it is possible to work around this particular problem by using the [`IdentityAgent` option in SSH_CONFIG](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5#IdentityAgent).

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly extracted from the excellant post [here](https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/stick-with-security-yubikey-ssh-gnupg-macos).

You need to make a plist file in your `~/Library/LaunchAgents` directory with the following content.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>link-ssh-auth-sock</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/bin/sh</string>
    <string>-c</string>
    <string>/bin/ln -sf $HOME/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh $SSH_AUTH_SOCK</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: This is a workaround, but doesn't really answer the specific question of how to actually set `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` to an arbitrary value system-wide. Which I'd love to know the answer to. As mentioned `launchctl setenv` doesn't seem to work for that particular environment variable.